# Vue router Back button leads to the wrong savedPosition

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have coded a vue 3 app with vue-router (4.0.13).
When I scroll a bit down on any page, then click a button to another route and then click the back button, the router leads me to a slightly different position than I was before.
But the Router should lead back to the exact same position as it was.

My router configuration:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    } else {
      return { top: 0, behavior: 'instant' }
    }
  }
})
```

When I remove the part "else {return { top: 0, behavior: 'instant' }}", then the back button behavior works fine.

What could be the issue here?
Here the link to my application: https://www.test.timetip.app/

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but I've seen `routes,` declared as `routes: [],`.. edit, on second thought, nah, this probably isn't involved

Comment: You may want to create and show a [mre] code post with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that pressing the browser back button was going to a different scroll position on the page than expected. In my case this was because I was using the vue router navigation guard `beforeEach` to enable a placeholder component in case the next route hadn't loaded completely (lazy loading). Unfortunately, `beforeEach` runs before vue router calculates and saves the scroll position of the page you are leaving, so it was calculating the scroll position for the page including the placeholder.

In general this behaviour could be caused by any parts of the html that get added or removed by javascript that runs just before vue router saves the scroll position.